# Add error parameter to Google reCaptcha

Tags: c#, asp.net, recaptcha

I'm having some trouble implementing reCapthca into an asp.net web form. I've read through the docs provided by Google but when I try to add the error parameter to the challenge url the reCaptcha doesn't do anything at all and just lets the user right through to my success page. If I don't add the parameter the reCaptcha functions properly but I can't seem to get an error message to display:

This is what I have in my webform:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=my_public_key&error=">
</script>

<noscript>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=my_public_key" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
<textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

And here is what I have in my codebehind:

```
Page.Validate();
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    Response.Redirect("success_page.aspx");
}
else
{
    Label errorMessage = (Label)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("ErrorMessage");
    errorMessage.Text = "Sorry, it looks like an error occurred while processing your request.";
}
```